# Mount GCP Persistent Disk as NFS

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, nfs

I am following [this article](https://medium.com/platformer-blog/nfs-persistent-volumes-with-kubernetes-a-case-study-ce1ed6e2c266) to use NFS volumes as persistent disks.

However, the disk does not mount to the NFS server. The error in the console:

```
MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "gce-nfs-disk" : mount failed: exit status 32 Mounting command: systemd-run Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/gce-pd/mounts/local-wikidata-gcd-dev-4gqr --scope -- mount -t ext4 -o defaults /dev/disk/by-id/google-local-wikidata-gcd-dev-4gqr /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/gce-pd/mounts/local-wikidata-gcd-dev-4gqr Output: Running scope as unit: run-r43178d69d92040cc9d36f72204438460.scope mount: /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/gce-pd/mounts/local-wikidata-gcd-dev-4gqr: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

The disk details are as follows:

```
Type: Standard persistent disk
Size: 2000 GB
Zone: europe-west1-b
In use by: ****
Snapshot schedule: None
Source image: debian-9-stretch-v20200805
Encryption type: Google-managed
```

Comment: nfs provisioner is already deprecated : https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nfs-server-provisioner

Comment: Please update your question with more details, preferably your yaml files, commands you're using to deploy everything etc.